# WooCommerce: Run filter inside action hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment

I'm working on a payment gateway plugin for WooCommerce and I need to edit the checkout form. When the user has selected 'Sweden' as their country, and they selected 'Klarna' as their payment method, an extra input field should appear for the user's social security number (this is totally normal in Sweden, really).

As far as I understand, the `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review` action gets triggered when something changes in the checkout form. I believe I can use the `woocommerce_get_country_locale` filter to add the social security number field for Swedish customers. So, inside my `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review` hook, I want to trigger the `woocommerce_get_country_locale` filter. How is this done?

Thanks in advance.